# Python Regex Matching Apostrophes

Tags: python, regex

```
re_newspeaker =         r'^(<bullet> |  )(?P<name>(%s|(((Mr)|(Ms)|(Mrs))\. [-A-Za-z \']+( of [A-Z][a-z]+)?))|((The ((VICE|ACTING|Acting) )?(PRESIDENT|SPEAKER|CHAIR(MAN)?)( pro tempore)?)|(The PRESIDING OFFICER)|(The CLERK)|(The CHIEF JUSTICE)|(The VICE PRESIDENT)|(Mr\. Counsel [A-Z]+))( \([A-Za-z.\'\- ]+\))?)\.'


re_speaking =           r'^(<bullet> |  )((((((Mr)|(Ms)|(Mrs))\. [A-Za-z \'\-]+(of [A-Z][a-z]+)?)|((The (VICE |Acting |ACTING )?(PRESIDENT|SPEAKER)( pro tempore)?)|(The PRESIDING OFFICER)|(The CLERK))( \([A-Za-z.\'\- ]+\))?))\. )?(?P<start>.)'
```

For some reason the above regex is not catching names with apostrophes.

For example: Mr. D'STALL
is not matched. Any help with the regex pattern would be most appreciated.

What the code does is takes the input and marks it up in XML. Such as the following would be:

```
<speaker=Mr. D'STALL</speaker><speaking>Mr. President, I have been seeking to obtain a report on
this bill. I am not on the Budget Committee, and I am not on the
Government Relations Committee. But from what I understand, this is a
very important bill, a big bill, a complex bill, far reaching in its
contents. I have been queried, along with all other Senators, I
suppose, as to whether or not they would have any objection to the
adoption of the committee amendments, en bloc. I am going to object to
the adoption of the committee amendments, en bloc, until I see the
committee report.</speaking>

  Mr. D'STALL. Mr. President, I have been seeking to obtain a report on
this bill. I am not on the Budget Committee, and I am not on the
Government Relations Committee. But from what I understand, this is a
very important bill, a big bill, a complex bill, far reaching in its
contents. I have been queried, along with all other Senators, I
suppose, as to whether or not they would have any objection to the
adoption of the committee amendments, en bloc. I am going to object to
the adoption of the committee amendments, en bloc, until I see the
committee report.
```

The regex will not match the above paragraph.

Comment: What a horrendously unmaintainable pattern you've got going there. I presume this issue affects both patterns?

Comment: http://regex101.com/r/dT6dN8/1

Comment: your regex needs to have a `space` or `bullet` at start.Is it there in your input?

Comment: I agree the regex pattern is a bit, unmaintainable. However, it is not mine. Yes there is either a bullet or space in front of the input. The only problem is it will not match Mr. D'STALL and yes it affects both patterns.

Comment: Check if the apostrophe is an ascii character not some unicode character which looks like apostrophe

Comment: D'STALL is an exact copy and paste it is definitely an '.

Comment: I see two regexes; which one causes the problem?

Comment: Both patterns cause the issue the first pattern identifies a new speaker and the second identifies who is speaking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
re_newspeaker =         r'^(<bullet> |  )(?P<name>(%s|(((Mr)|(Ms)|(Mrs))\. [-A-Z\']+|((Miss) [-A-Z\']+)( of [A-Z][a-z]+)?))|((The ((VICE|ACTING|Acting) )?(PRESIDENT|SPEAKER|CHAIR(MAN)?)( pro tempore)?)|(The PRESIDING OFFICER)|(The CLERK)|(The CHIEF JUSTICE)|(The VICE PRESIDENT)|(Mr\. Counsel [A-Z]+))( \([A-Za-z.\- ]+\))?)\.'

re_speaking =           r'^(<bullet> |  )((((((Mr)|(Ms)|(Mrs))\. [A-Z\']+|((Miss) [-A-Z\']+)(of [A-Z][a-z]+)?)|((The (VICE |Acting |ACTING )?(PRESIDENT|SPEAKER)( pro tempore)?)|(The PRESIDING OFFICER)|(The CLERK))( \([A-Za-z.\- ]+\))?))\. )?(?P<start>.)'
```

The above RegEx solved my issue. I thought I would post it if anyone else had this issue!

Comment: Could you please explain what you did to solve your issue?